# Placing Dynamic Values in Spring Message Code

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, dynamic, message

In my spring application, I have key in message properties are :

currentYear = the Year is {0,currentYear}

The problem is solved is its just {0} instead of {0, currentYear}

But I want to have {0,currentYear} only

Now, in JSP's I want it to be displayed dynamically based on Java.Calendar
Like
the Year is 2013

How can I achieve that ?

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand your need. {0} will be resolved by the parameter you give when get the message. What does "currentYear" mean?

Comment: I just need to have currentYear as I have some non-spring java code which takes {0, currentYear} and replaces it with year.

Comment: But spring should just consider {0, currentYear} as a placeholder only like {0}